# Voyager - Can we send e-mail when admin add user?

Tags: laravel, email, voyager

I am trying send information e-mail to user when admin add user. But i don't know how can i intervene the Userpage in Adminpanel?

For example: Welcome "`$user->name`", your username is "$`user->username`" and your password is "`$user->password`".

I think about a lot. But can't progress. Still can not send any email. Do we have a way to make this e-mailing system easier in voyager tables?

edit: Added Registercontroller

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validation($request);
    $customer = new Customer();
    $customer->name = $request->name;
    $customer->surname = $request->surname;
    $customer->phone = $request->phone;
    $customer->email = $request->email;
    $customer->password = bcrypt($request->password);
    $customer->description = $request->password;
    $customer->save();
    Auth::guard('customer')->login($customer);
    Session::flash('success', __('messages.success'));
    return redirect('/');
```

edit: Added CustomerObserve.php

```
    <?php

namespace App\Helper\Observers;
use App\Customer;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class CustomerObserve implements ShouldQueue
{
    public function created()
    {
        $customer = Customer::latest();
        Mail::send('user_login_informations', ['customer' => $customer], function($message) use($customer) {
            $message->to($customer->email, $customer->name)
                ->subject('account update');
    })->delay(30);
}
}
```

Comment: you can send the email when the user is stored in the database. share your code to store user.

Comment: Added RegisterController.

Comment: is the issue resolved

Comment: No sir. I need insert these codes to observe event into created function. But can't made this. It tries to send email like 30 times. But not sending. Question edited.

Comment: do you get data of customer

Comment: yes. I need to mail with queue. So i have jobs table and in the jobs table i can get the data from customer. But jobs are just waiting. Queue:work doesn't working.

Answer (score 0):

**create an email template in view folder**

**email.blade.php**

```
@section('content')
<h2>Hello {{ ucfirst($customer->name) }},</h2>
    <p>
       Your email '{{ $customer->email }}' and password {{ $customer->password }}.
   </p>
@stop
```

**Reviewer controller**

```
$this->validation($request);
$customer = new Customer();
$customer->name = $request->name;
$customer->surname = $request->surname;
$customer->phone = $request->phone;
$customer->email = $request->email;
$customer->password = bcrypt($request->password);
$customer->description = $request->password;
$customer->save();
Auth::guard('customer')->login($customer);
Session::flash('success', __('messages.success'));

Mail::send('email', ['customer' => $customer], function($message) use($customer) {
    $message->to($customer->email, $customer->name)
            ->subject('account update');
});
return redirect('/');
```